# How to plot mean values with standard deviation

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, mean, standard-deviation

I have a dataframe D looking similiar to this:

```
 Temp      A      B
  14      10      14
  14      11      13
  14      12      15
  14      14      18
  16      18      17
  16      20      17
  16      22      18
  16      22      17
  18      25      25
  18      26      27
  18      28      26
  18      26      28
```

There is always the same amount of values for each temperature step.

What I want to do: plot the mean values and standard deviation of A and B for each temperature step. Is it possible to do so without subdividing the dataframe?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: this gives you the mean/sd for A and B per temp: `aggregate(.~Temp,df,function(x) c(M=mean(x),SD=sd(x)))`, not sure what you want to plot or how

Answer (score 1):

GGplot tends to want you to have your data in long form already at the desired level of aggregation. So I would first melt it so that your values are in one column, and then would use data.table's syntax to create a summary dataset with your means and standard deviations then melt that summary and then plot the mean temperature and standard deviations separately.

```
 meltedTable = melt(table, id.vars = c("temp"))
 summaryTemps = meltedTable[,list(Mean = mean(value), StandardDeviation =   sd(value)), by = list(temp, variable)]
 meanTemperatures = ggplot(summaryTemps) + geom_line(aes(x = summaryTemps$temp, y = summaryTemps$Mean, colour = summaryTemps$variable))
 sdTemperatures = ggplot(summaryTemps) + geom_line(aes(x = summaryTemps$temp, y = summaryTemps$StandardDeviation, colour = summaryTemps$variable))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find other ways also,
try the following code:

```
df<-split(df,df$Temp)

df<-lapply(df,function(x){
     A.mean<-mean(x[,1])
     A.sd<-sd(x[,1])
     B.mean<-mean(x[,2])
     B.sd<-sd(x[,2])
     x<-rbind(A.mean,A.sd,B.mean,B.sd)
     x
}
)

df<-do.call("rbind",df)

df<-as.data.frame(df)
df$Variable<-rownames(df)

df$Count<-rep(1:(nrow(df))/4,each=4)
rownames(df)<-NULL

ggplot(df,aes(Count,V1))+geom_line+facet_wrap(~Variable,scales="free",ncol=2)
```